# Dynamic ASP.NET code generation "User extending form fields by clicking a button"

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I am looking for a way to repeat the following code whenever the user presses the "Add More" button.  There are two issues that I'm not sure how to get around in this scenario,

1- If I use Literal control, I would not be able to embed ASP.NET controls in them.  What are the alternatives if any?
2- Since the number of cases shown depend on the number of request by the client, how can I accomplish this so that with every "Add More" click by the user, a new set of fields appear for the client's input.

```
<div class="controls controls-row">
    <div class="span3">
        <asp:Label ID="CarouselTextLabel" CssClass="control-label" Text="Carousel Text" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="CarouselText" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="50" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        <asp:Label ID="UploadImageText" CssClass="control-label" Text="Upload Slide" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" />
        <asp:FileUpload ID="UploadSlideImage" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        <asp:Label ID="ButtonLabel" CssClass="control-label" Text="Button Label" runat="server" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="ButtonLabelText" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        <asp:Label ID="ButtonLinkLabel" CssClass="control-label" Text="Button Link" runat="server" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="ButtonLinkLabelText" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
<p class="stdformbutton">
    <asp:Button ID="AddMore" Text="Add More" CssClass="btn-rounded btn-warning" OnClick="AddMoreSlidesToCarousel" runat="server" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use the `Placeholder` control instead of a Literal.
2. See this SO question and answers. [Dynamically add a new text box when clicking a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488006/dynamically-add-a-new-text-box-when-clicking-a-button)

Comment: Now that you created these dynamic controls, how would you be able to read off these dynamically generated ID field?  For instance how do you treat "CarouselText + i.ToString()" as id so that you could read the text off it?

Comment: I think you need another question for that, or maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763050/accessing-controls-added-programmatically-on-postback?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

I would use a template based databound control like a Repeater control. It let's you define arbitrary mark-up that will repeat based on a databound data source

Comment: Many thanks for prompt reply.  Could you please give an example or elaborate a little more.  Regards